# is there a way to select a dropdown value from partial visible text as there a method : selectByVisibleText(dropdownvalue);

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, select, methods, dropdown

```
switch (valuetype.toLowerCase()) {
LazyWebElement selectelement = getElement(element);
        Select statusselect = new Select(selectelement);
        case "text":
            statusselect.selectByVisibleText(values);
            break;
        case "value":
            statusselect.selectByValue(values);
            break;`
}
```

i want to add one more method here that will select the dropdown value from partial text
eg: the  dropdown value is below as
"abc efgh"
when i give the value just "abc" it must selectthe above dropdown
where in the code i given above i have to fully give "abc efgh"

i want to inculate case or a method in the above code to make the code work to select partially given text dropdown,
thanks